# How to upload project files?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

For **complex answers or questions** like:

- [vary the color of repeated shape in After Effects](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/vary-the-color-of-repeated-shape-in-after-effects)
- [Add path operation to multiple shape layers](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15230/add-path-operation-to-multiple-shape-layers/15232#15232)
- [Footprint or breadcrumb animation](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14592/footprint-or-breadcrumb-animation/)

it would be useful to **provide the project files for clearification**. I don't want to use my own Dropbox because I could delete the files accidentally.

Is there a way to enable uploading of **After Effects, Blender, Fusion or Natron or at least Zip files** on this site? If we can't, does anyone knows another site or platform to share files without registration?

Answer (score 2):

For xdadevelopers they tend to use mediafire for that. It's kind of obnoxious but pretty good at persistent online storage. I'm not sure if se may want to provide a local solution or not, but historically they seem to prefer integrating external tools. Won't know for sure until some se staff answer here.

Comment: Thanks AJ! Hopefully there is a better one without registration :)

Comment: Any site that allows you to upload files without registration is going to quickly become a hive of pr0n and piracy. What would be great is something like github that could deal with the various project file formats, so people could fork and modify projects with proper version control. But given the complexities of the various proprietary project file formats it would be tricky.